# Question abut poisson distribution in university stats

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Given that new fabric getting of a loom has an average of 1.3 tear every 10 feet. What is the probability that:

a) There is more than 10 feet between the next two tears? I have absolutely no idea how to solve this. Do i reformulate? Do i use exponential function?

b)There is no tear in the 5 feet getting out of the loom? for this one i got 52.20% because i did (=POISSON.DIST(0,0.65,FALSE)) on excel

I’d appreciate any help understanding how I can properly answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

Poisson distribution:  $p_k=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$, where $p_k$ is the probability of exactly $k$ events during the interval in question.

For a) $\lambda=1.3$ and you want $p_0=e^{-1.3}=0.2725$.

For b) $\lambda=0.65$ and you want $p_0=e^{-0.65}$, which is your answer.

Comment: thank you but could you explain how you got those? and why is the second one exponential as well?

Comment: As long as the tears are random, they follow a Poisson distribution.  $\lambda$ is the average number of events for the interval in question.  $p_0$ is the probability that there are no events during this interval.

Comment: could u further break down the first one please? what was taught in class was that we use exponential function when trying to determine time between events and poisson when we want to determine events in an interval

Comment: As you can see $p_0$ is the exponential distribution, with $\lambda=xr$ where $r$ is the rate per unit interval and $x$ isthe fraction of the unit interval.  For your problem $r=1.3$ and a) has $x=1$ while b) has $x=0.5$.

Comment: thank you! but why is it 0.5?

Comment: Unit length is $10$ feet so $.5$ is $5$ feet.

Comment: so for a), i follow exponential, and b) i follow poisson?

Comment: As you may have noted Poisson and exponential are related.  I just use Poisson.  However when asking about interval length (exponential) you can use Poisson-zero with varying parameter, so it amounts to the same.  Personally I don't worry too much about labels.